# Showing an ideal is prime in polynomial ring: over $\Bbb Q$ and $\Bbb C$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ideals, irreducible-polynomials, maximal-and-prime-ideals

So i'm trying to understand the following computation

> $(x_1^2-2x_2^2)$ is a prime ideal in $\Bbb Q[x_1,x_2]$ but not in $\Bbb C[x_1,x_2]$

I only know that both polynomial rings are UFD. I wonder what are the standard strategies for such computations.

Comment: In a $\text{UFD}$, an element is prime iff it is irreducible. Can $x_1^2-2x_2^2$ be expressed as a product of two non-units in $\mathbb{Q}[x_1,x_2]\,$?$\;$Same question for $\mathbb{C}[x_1,x_2]$.

Comment: I see, so you mean i just write it out in general form, i.e. solve coeficients for polynomial product?  I was thinking more if there is some more general argument. Yea I see why it is not prime in $\Bbb C[x_1,x_2]$ now.  $(x_1-\sqrt{2}x_2)(x_1+\sqrt{2}x_2)$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that in both $\mathbb{Q}[x_1,x_2]$ and $\mathbb{C}[x_1,x_2]$, the units are the constant polynomials.

Let $f=x_1^2-2x_2^2$.

In $\mathbb C[x_1,x_2]$ we have the factorization
$$
x_1^2-2x_2^2=(x_1+\sqrt{2}x_2)(x_1-\sqrt{2}x_2)
$$
hence $f$ is not irreducible in $\mathbb{C}[x_1,x_2]$.

Note also that the factors $x_1+\sqrt{2}x_2$ and $x_1-\sqrt{2}x_2$ are irreducible in $\mathbb{C}[x_1,x_2]$, so they are the unique irreducible factors of $f$ in $\mathbb{C}[x_1,x_2]$ (unique up to nonzero constant multiple).

Suppose $f$ could be expressed as $gh$ where $g,h\in\mathbb{Q}[x_1,x_2]$ are non-constant.

Then the factorization $f=gh$ would still work in $\mathbb{C}[x_1,x_2]$, hence, since $\mathbb{C}[x_1,x_2]$ is a $\text{UFD}$, it follows that $g=a(x_1+bx_2)$ for some nonzero $a\in \mathbb{C}$ and some $b\in\{\pm\sqrt{2}\}$.

Since $g\in\mathbb{Q}[x_1,x_2]$, we must have $a\in\mathbb{Q}$ (since $a$ is the coefficient of the $x_1$ term of $g$), and we must also have $ab\in\mathbb{Q}$ (since $ab$ is the coefficient of the $x_2$ term of $g$).

But then we would have ${\Large{\frac{ab}{a}}}=b\in\mathbb{Q}$, contradiction.

Therefore $f$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{Q}[x_1,x_2]$.